# Thread issues in JFrame

Tags: java, swing

This was a small assignment given.A JFrame program had to written such that when you click a button another button in the same panel ;the y in button.setBound(x,y,l,b); would decrease by a factor of 100 and stay at that location for some time and return to its original position.
Now the Problem arises that when I press the button the another button jumps but not always. At some clicks it doesn't jumps altogether--and that is happening arbitrarily.

What is it  that my code could is missing?
PS-the JFrame was created by using the drag-drop palette in eclipse so most the code is automatically generated.

```
int jy=325,jx=214;
int x=325;
int o1x=403,o1y=359;//global in class

public void run()
{
  int xo1=o1x;
  while(true)
  {
    action.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) 
        {           
            jumper.setBounds(jx, jy-100, 23, 70);
        }
    });


    try{sleep(750);}catch(Exception e){}

    jumper.setBounds(jx, jy, 23, 70);
    xo1=xo1-50;

    if(xo1<=100)
    {
        xo1=o1x;
    }

    obs1.setBounds(xo1, o1y, 12, 35);
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show some of your relevant code?

Comment: Take a look at [ask]

Comment: @Florian S.  -have added the code for your kind referral and perusal.:-)

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't see all your code, I can only guess. What is the LayoutManager you are using? Is it a null layout? Otherwise the `setBounds` method may eventually not really work.

If you have a null layout (what should do absolute positioning), you may need to repaint the parent component of `jumper` after calling `setBounds()` when `jumper` is already visible. To do so, try the following:

```
parent.revalidate();
parent.repaint();
```